# Laravel where on object not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have:

```
public function fetchProducts($filters = array()) {
    print_r($filters);
    $Product = new Product;
    if (array_key_exists('search', $filters))
        $Product->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filters['search'].'%');
    if (array_key_exists('type', $filters))
        $Product->where('type_id', 1);
    if (array_key_exists('brand', $filters))
        $Product->where('brand_id', $filters['brand']);

    $Product->get();
    return $Product;
}
```

But no matter what filter comes in it returns all products and seems to ignore everything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using Eloquent ORM??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you're calling where on an instance of the `Product` model. What you want to do instead is call it on a query builder instance. You do that by first calling `query()`

```
$Product = Product::query();

if (array_key_exists('search', $filters))
    $Product->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filters['search'].'%');
if (array_key_exists('type', $filters))
    $Product->where('type_id', 1);
if (array_key_exists('brand', $filters))
    $Product->where('brand_id', $filters['brand']);

$Product->get();
```

Comment: That gives me the error: syntax error, unexpected 'query' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Comment: Ooops obviously there's no need for the `new` since we're calling a  static method

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now my pagination won't work: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()

Comment: You need to call `paginate()` instead of `get()`

Answer (score 3):

Can use

```
public function fetchProducts($filters = array()) {
print_r($filters);

$Product_query = Product::select('//values'); // i have mostly used like this
if (array_key_exists('search', $filters))
    $Product_query ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filters['search'].'%');
if (array_key_exists('type', $filters))
    $Product_query ->where('type_id', 1);
if (array_key_exists('brand', $filters))
    $Product_query ->where('brand_id', $filters['brand']);

$Product  =  $Product_query ->get();
   //or
$Product  =  $Product_query ->paginate();   //can also pass the paginate value like paginate($perPage)
return $Product; 
}
```

comment for changes...